# Test URLSession Delegates with mock data

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, urlsession

We have 2 URLSession Delegates that are in use with custom code in their bodies(not shown to make this post cleaner):

```
   public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {}

  public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
     if let error = error {
            //code here
        } else if let response = task.response as? HTTPURLResponse, var dataResponse = self.dataReceived {
            if (400...499).contains(response.statusCode) {
                //handle response here
            }
}
```

We have a mockURLSession class:

```
protocol URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
    func resume()
}

protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    typealias DataTaskResult = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void

    func dataTask(with request: Request, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
}

class MockURLSession: URLSessionProtocol {

    typealias DataTaskResult = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void
    var nextDataTask = MockURLSessionDataTask()
    var nextData: Data?
    var nextError: Error?

    private (set) var lastURL: URL?

    func successHttpURLResponse(request: Request) -> URLResponse {
        return HTTPURLResponse(url: request.url!, statusCode: 200, httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1", headerFields: nil)!
    }

    func wrongHttpURLResponse(request: Request, statusCode:Int) -> URLResponse {
        return HTTPURLResponse(url: request.url!, statusCode: statusCode, httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1", headerFields: nil)!
    }

    func dataTask(with request: Request, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
        lastURL = request.url
        nextDataTask.resume()
        completionHandler(nextData, successHttpURLResponse(request: request), nextError)
        return nextDataTask
    }

}

class MockURLSessionDataTask: URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
    private (set) var resumeWasCalled = false

    func resume() {
        resumeWasCalled = true
    }
}
```

The issue we are having is I have to write unit tests for specific responses from the mock server(ex. 404).  Typically I would write the response like this:

```
  let urlReponse = MockURLSession().wrongHttpURLResponse(request: self.urlRequest!, statusCode: 404)
```

The problem I'm having is since we are using the URLSession delegates I can't inject the mockResponse into the function as a parameter unless it won't get called. What would be the best way to test the URLSession delegates based of mock responses?

Comment: If you only want to test the delegate, you can directly call it in your test case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject the mock response when you init the `MockURLSession`.

Add the following to your `MockURLSession`:

```
private var mockResponse: HTTPURLResponse?

init() { }
init(mockResponse: HTTPURLResponse) {
    self.mockResponse = mockResponse
}
```

Modify your mock's `dataTask` function to call the completion handler with your mock response, if you provided it:

```
if let mockResponse = mockResponse {
    completionHandler(nextData, mockResponse, nextError)
}
else {
    //default case is success
    completionHandler(nextData, successHttpURLResponse(request: request), nextError)
}
```

Now when you want to test an error response, inject it when you create the mock session:

```
let mockResponse = HTTPURLResponse(url: self.urlRequest.url!, statusCode: 404, httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1", headerFields: nil)!
let mockURLSession = MockURLSession(mockResponse: mockResponse)
```

When `dataTask` is called, your mock response will be used:

```
mockURLSession.dataTask(with: self.urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
    if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print("Status Code: \(response.statusCode)") // "Status Code: 404"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really good stuff, thanks a lot.  But when I try and insert the mockUrlSession into the urlSession delegate as a parameter:  sut?.urlSession(mockURLSession, task:URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError: Error?), it complains with error: /Users/justin/Code/EComAPI/EComAPI/EComAPITests/CoreTests/DownloadTests.swift:58:24: Cannot call value of non-function type 'URLSession'

Comment: That's because your method expects URLSession. You'll either have to change your mock to inherit from URLSession, or change your method to accept URLSessionProtocol. And that will undoubtedly entail other changes, which I'm not able to look into right now. I'll try to have a look later today.

Comment: I think it would help to post a new question with your latest code and how you're trying to call it. I'm not sure what your .urlSession method is designed to do.

Comment: I updated the question in another post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866777/cannot-call-value-of-non-function-type-urlsession-error-with-mockurlsession